# C++11 GCC 5.1.1 array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Tags: c++11, stdstring, stdarray

This initialization of a `std::array` of strings fails:

```
const std::array<std::string, 1> str_array {"Text"};
```

Error message from gcc 5.1.1 is:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Edit: This form of initialization also fails:

```
const std::array<std::string, 1> str_array = {"Text"};
```

Edit 2: Only this form works:

```
const std::array<std::string, 1> str_array {{"Text"}};
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OXwkc12ndZk0BzAQ).

Comment: @T.C.: It says 5.1.1 not 5.1.0.

Comment: @Mehrdad OK, then I couldn't care less about a (possible) bug in a development version of GCC that doesn't reproduce in any released version.

Comment: Yes this must be a bug because `str_array = {"Text"};` also fails, which shouldn't.

Comment: Yes the array is initialized in header file since it's a `const` type anyway.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65815, then. Include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time, or at least the full context.